# pointwise bounded set

Tags: functional-analysis

M is a set and pointwise bounded on 
$
{C}\left[{a\mathrm{,}b}\right]
$

Then show that the following set is pre-compact

$
{N}\mathrm{\equiv}\left\{{{y}{\mathrm{(}}{t}{\mathrm{)}}\mathrm{{=}}\mathop{\int}\limits_{0}\limits^{t}{{x}{\mathrm{(}}\mathit{\tau}{\mathrm{)}}{d}\mathit{\tau}{\mathrm{,}}\hspace{0.33em}{x}{\mathrm{(}}{t}{\mathrm{)}}\mathrm{\in}{M}}}\right\}
$

Comment: Do you know the definition of a precompact set? If yes, have you tried anything at all ?

Comment: Pre compact set that it's closure is compact

Comment: I tried by ascoli arzela

Comment: Correct. Now what is the definition of a set being compact?

Comment: I think if we prove that the set is equicontiuous we will have the wanted

Comment: That's a good observation. So you need to show that the set is equicontinuous and pointwise bounded. Can you write out what you tried?

Comment: It's just ideas

Comment: Well, what does it mean for a set to be equicontinuous? Questions like this are often easy to tackle if you write down what you want to prove.

Comment: Your integral isn't well defined if $0\notin[a,b]$...